# How can I run Python on Idle?

Tags: python-idle

In Windows, the shortcut for running Python from a working file in the IDLE shell is F5, this is not so in Mac. In Mac instead it asks me at first to save the file and then I can run it; F5 is no option. Is there a trick to run the code with just one click in Mac?

Thanks,

Comment: Has anyone found any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

In this respect, IDLE should work the same on all platforms.  Whether or not IDLE asks before saving when you hit F5 is a configuration option.  On Options => IDLE Preferences => Settings dialog, General tab, find

```
Autosave Preferences
At Start of Run (F5)      O Prompt to Save    O No Prompt
```

I presume you have `Prompt to Save` (the default) set on Mac, and `No Prompt` set on Windows.